# mongoose: find value inside object, inside array inside array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hello and sorry for the title,
it is quite hard to explain with words.

I have a data with multiples level :

-strategyParameters -> [wsent -> [ {confirmationCandle.timestamp} ] ]

I am trying to request documents, having inside wSent, inside strategyParameters, a confirmationCandle timestamp greater than a certain value.
I have tried several attemps with some things similar to this :

```
db.getCollection('users').find({"exchange":"binance","pair":"LTCUSDT","timeframe":"1h","wSent.confirmationCandle.timestamp":{"$gt":1606644800000}})
```

But it was unsuccessful, any help would be much appreciated.

bellow a concrete example of document inside my db:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5fd7b0f1356b89312949963a"),
"email" : "test@test.com",
"password" : "$2b$10$egeg",
"strategyParameters" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5fd7c9940d0f3033fc527547"),
        "pair" : "LTCUSDT",
        "strategy" : "w",
        "timeframe" : "1h",
        "exchange" : "binance",
        "wSent" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5fd7adb9d157b430a05a87b1"),
                "firstBottom" : {
                    "open" : 79.46,
                    "high" : 80.07,
                    "low" : 78.29,
                    "close" : 78.91,
                    "timestamp" : 1606690800000.0,
                    "isTop" : false,
                    "isBottom" : true
                },
                "top" : {
                    "open" : 78.89,
                    "high" : 80.5,
                    "low" : 78.87,
                    "close" : 79.7,
                    "timestamp" : 1606694400000.0,
                    "isTop" : true,
                    "isBottom" : false
                },
                "seconBottom" : {
                    "open" : 79.73,
                    "high" : 79.84,
                    "low" : 78.55,
                    "close" : 79.29,
                    "timestamp" : 1606698000000.0,
                    "isTop" : false,
                    "isBottom" : true
                },
                "confirmationCandle" : {
                    "open" : 81.56,
                    "high" : 85,
                    "low" : 81.1,
                    "close" : 83.24,
                    "timestamp" : 1606744800000.0, <-- the target
                    "isTop" : false,
                    "isBottom" : false
                },
                "exchange" : "binance",
                "pair" : "LTCUSDT",
                "timeframe" : "1h"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't match because the fields you're searching for don't align with the document's structure. The sample document doesn't have `exchange`, `pair`, `timeframe` or `wSent.confirmationCandle.timestamp` fields. But it *does* have `strategyParameters.wSent.exchange`, `strategyParameters.wSent.pair`, `strategyParameters.wSent.timeframe` and `strategyParameters.wSent.confirmationCandle.timestamp` fields.

Your query should look something like this:

```
db.getCollection("users").find({
  "strategyParameters.wSent.exchange": "binance",
  "strategyParameters.wSent.pair": "LTCUSDT",
  "strategyParameters.wSent.timeframe": "1h",
  "strategyParameters.wSent.confirmationCandle.timestamp": { $gt :1606644800000 }
})
```